# Not committing a message from Apache Kafka if exception occurs while operations in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Sometimes, while processing and during sink I am getting few exceptions because of network. I want these message not to be committed so that they can be re processed sometimes in future.

**Is there any way to achieve such functionality where I could ignore that individual message from offset commit, so that it can be processed sometimes in future?**

*One solution, I am currently following is to sink those messages to other topic which we process later.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of writing messages with errors during processing to a "dead letter queue" is a common and useful pattern.  It's also pretty simple and straightforward. Don't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

If any exception occurred during processing of a message, the task will be restarted until this message has been eventually processed. Offsets are only committed for messages that have been fully processed.

So if you don't change anything to the error handling in source and sink, you will get exactly your desired behavior (also known as [at-least once guarantee](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/internals/stream_checkpointing.html#exactly-once-vs-at-least-once)).

Btw, I recommend you to fix your tags.

Comment: But restarting the task is a costly operation when processing large bandwidth of data. How can this be achieved to have a special handling to the specific message.

Currently I am sinking those message to other Kafka topic which has higher retention to be processed later.

Comment: As pointed out by Chris, a dead letter queue is a common approach. However, that is used more often, when the message itself is invalid. A dead letter queue will change the message order, which is often not desired. Note, that the source offsets of these messages are then committed. If that is fine, then I guess, I misunderstood your question and a dead letter queue is a valid approach.

Comment: If it's about system stability, I'd still propose to let the framework handle it. This will retain message order (if producer is correctly configured). In most cases, it's enough to simply increase the retries on writing to Kafka. If network is flaky, your throughput will suffer anyways, so having a restart of the Flink job after unsuccessful X retries (=network down for several minutes), shouldn't make a huge difference anyways.

Comment: To be more specific here, by network I meant an API call to another server that is using rocks db internally. If I get socket timeout for more than 3 retires I assume that the message needs to go to _**dead-letter-queue**_ to be processed later. The percentage of bad messages is less than 0.05% but still I want to develop a system to reduce these errors as well. As suggested, I would go by dead-letter-queue, as for such error rate we can afford to loose order but since input data is very large, restarting job would not be desirable. Thanks for the help.